# reactjs Can't get the ID by using querySelector - ID value is generated from data reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I trying to get the specified ID of the div when on click by using querySelector to query the ID that I want, it showing error below:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#3dCubeSlider' is not a valid selector.

*Here is the simplified codes*

```
const Gallery = () => {

// some code that handling data from database

function handleShowGifDemo(e) {
  var parent = e.currentTarget.parentNode.id; // the id will be "3Dslider"
  var staticImg = document.querySelector("#" + parent); // This return the Error message
}
return (
<div className="content-bottom">
 <div className="grid-layout row"> 

  {gallery.map((value, key) => {
     return (
       <div id={value.tempid} className={value.tempid +" " +filtercategory +" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center mb-5 align-items-stretch flex-column align-items-stretch gallery-box"} name="data_container" key={key}>
          <div className="demo-gif"></div>
          <div className="show-gif" onClick={handleShowGifDemo}>
              <i className="far fa-play-circle"></i>
          </div>
   </div>
</div>
)}
```

}

Wondering how to get the dynamic ID name when onClick?

Comment: It's because `#3Dslider` is not a valid selector (ID cannot start with a number). Also note that you might use `document.getElementById()` without this trouble. With that said, why do you need it? You already have it `onClick={() => console.info(value.tempid)}` (even easier if you define a separate `GalleryItem` component). Another thing: a `div` with `onClick` without `role` (and keyboard support and an alt title for the _icon_)  isn't a good thing for accessibility. One last thing: why do you use the `index` as `key` when you've got an ID?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I totally forgot that ID can't be start with number, thanks for the help!  
you may ignore rest code can be ignore as I just test around and did not clean it up